# Using Selenium Chromedriver with python how do i click this element?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, bots

I am want to be able to click this element in the Yandex account sign up page.

I am using Selenium Chromedriver with python.

https://passport.yandex.com/registration/

[image: I want to automate clicking this element.]

I have tried this code

```
element = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("toggle-link.link_has-no-phone").click()
        webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()
```

but I get ElementClickInterceptedException.

Comment: After selecting it in code, You'll have something like .click() or whatever (I don't remember exactly haven't used selenium for a year), You can also use `ActionChains` and this is the _humanic_ way to do it, for evading robot checkers and these kinds of stuff

Comment: Thanks, I have tried the code you suggested but unfortunately didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `element.click().perform()`

and you can also send a `Return` key to the element

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


element = ... # get your element
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) # or send a left mouse click
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the way you're finding the element is wrong, there are two classes for that element and you have tried to specify both -> find_element_by_class_name only takes one class attribute value.

So, this should work for you

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('link_has-no-phone').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are using `ActionChains` here while you can simply click on the mentioned link.

Simplified code

```
self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("toggle-link.link_has-no-phone").click()
```

OR

```
element = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("toggle-link.link_has-no-phone")
element.click()
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.toggle-link.link_has-no-phone').click()
```

Comment: none of these work. I have tried these before posting the question.  I get a 'ElementClickInterceptedException' which means that Yandex knows i am using automation software to try and click that specific element, and then blocks me from doing so.

Comment: There might be something. You should add complete code in your question because I've tried with above mentioned code and it is working for me without any hassle.